# Create different Indesign documents with Scripting

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is their a way to create different Indesign documents,
based on paper size, bleed, margin, columns ect.
I'm thinking about a JSON file that haves all the data or something.

I know that you can use Indesign scripting with Javascript,
but can that create different files? How, and does Indesign haves to be open.
Or is it also possible to run a Indesign script from CMD of Shell?

Answer (score 2):

An InDesign script can make a new document with properties that specify the page height and page width. You can also change those properties after the new document is made.
InDesign must be running in order for it to execute a script.

If you want to trigger the script from CMD you'll need to write a VB script that talks to InDesign and tells it to run the jsx. Or you could write the entire script in VB script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Document.save(filename)`](http://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign11/#Document.html#d1e47047__d1e51915) after your [extendscript](/questions/tagged/extendscript) modified the file. This requires InDesign running. Also note potential reflow problems.

Alternatively, check the [IDML specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs55-docs/IDML/idml-specification.pdf), with which you can create InDesign documents via a bundle of XML files without requiring InDesign itself. The reflow problems remain though...